# Regex to check if String is one word in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I need regex to check if String has only one word (e.g. "This", "Country", "Boston ", " Programming ").

So far I used an alternative way of doing it which is to check if String contains spaces. However, I am sure that this can be done using regex.

One possible way in my opinion is `"^\w{2,}\s"`. Does this work properly? Are there any other possible answers?

Comment: What do you mean by "one word"? Simply that it is non-empty and contains no whitespace? If so, `^\S+$` would work.

Comment: The title of your question and the first sentence can be interpreted differently.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I edited it so it is more clear.

Comment: @AndyTurner by one word I mean it has exactly one word. I edited the question so that it is more clear.

Comment: Your own attempted regex makes no sense in regard to your question since your explicitly *added* a whitespace at the end of your pattern.

Comment: @JvdV I see a space after for example `"Boston "`.

Comment: So OP has possible leading/trailing spaces? In such an event maybe `^\s*\S+\s*$` works. Maybe this question can better be resolved in a different way, possibly at the source of the data?

Comment: The pattern `^\w{2,}\s` matches 2 or more word characters from the start of the string, followed by a mandatory whitespace char. It depends on what the requirement for a "word" is, but in Java you could also write `^\h*\w{2,}\h*$` https://regex101.com/r/eFDjky/1

Comment: And what is the definition of word? (are numbers, special chars and umlauts allowed?)

Comment: @Turo the word, in this case, is considered to be the simple sequence of characters, so no special characters are included.

Comment: @Thefourthbird the regexp that you suggested seems to work fine. Thank you!

Comment: @GIO \w includes digits and the underscore, is that right?

Comment: @Turo \w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

Comment: Checking for spaces, like you were doing originally, is going to be a lot faster than using a regex.  What’s wrong with `s.trim().contains(" ")`?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `^\w{2,}\s` matches 2 or more word characters from the start of the string, followed by a mandatory whitespace char (that can also match a newline)

As the pattern is also unanchored, it can also match `Boston` in `Boston test`

If you want to match a single word with as least 2 characters surrounded by optional horizontal whitespace characters using `\h*` and add an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string.

```
^\h*\w{2,}\h*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HcsN4I/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "^\\h*\\w{2,}\\h*$";
```

Comment: In Java, string’s matches method must match the *entire* string: the leading `^` and trailing `$` are redundant and may be removed without affecting anything. Your comment about unanchored is incorrect: it will **not** match “Boston test”

Comment: @Bohemian There is no notion of the .matches method.

Comment: How else would you check if a String matches a regex?

Comment: @Bohemian The pattern by itself can get a partial match. There is no notion about how the pattern is used. If one decides to use Matcher with find, you could get a partial match https://ideone.com/60DUcJ But .matches would indeed be a better choice.